# The page don't refresh . Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I tried to build this javascript calculator, but there is a problem. When I enter values it's working well. But the problem is when I refresh the page, she's doesn't refresh; she only saves the first values that were entered. Why?

```js
var 
    displayResultBtn = document.querySelector('#calc-btn'),
    backToInputBtn = document.querySelector('#back-input');

var 
    inputPage = document.querySelector('#data-inputs'),
    outputPage = document.querySelector('#data-outputs');

/* ========== Go to Result ========== */
displayResultBtn.addEventListener('click', displayResult);

function displayResult(){

    var 
        coutJour = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#cj-input').value),
        nbrJour = parseInt(document.querySelector('#nj-input').value),
        prime;

    // calcul Base Salary
    slrBase = coutJour * nbrJour;


    if(nbrJour>=25){
        prime = 200;
    }
    else if(nbrJour>=20){
        prime = 150;
    }
    else if(nbrJour>=15){
        prime = 100;
    }
    else if(nbrJour<15){
        prime = 50;
    }

    //calcul Net Salary
    var slrNet = slrBase + prime;

    //display results in his places
    document.querySelector('#slrBase-result').innerHTML = slrBase + " $";
    document.querySelector('#prime-result').innerHTML = prime + " $";
    document.querySelector('#slrNet-result').innerHTML = slrNet + " $",
    document.querySelector('#slrNet-result').style.color = "red";

    // display the result Page
    inputPage.style.display = "none";
    outputPage.style.display = "flex";
}

/* ========== Back to inputs ========== */
backToInputBtn.addEventListener('click', displayInputs);

function displayInputs(){
    outputPage.style.display = "none";
    inputPage.style.display = "initial";
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 10% 85% 5%;
}


/* ========== Header ========== */
header{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #a52a2a;
}

header h1{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .05rem;
    color: #fff;
}

main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* ========== Input ========== */
#data-inputs{
    display: initial;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 25px;
}
  
.inputs{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

input{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
}

input::placeholder{
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

input:focus{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a52a2a;
}

.btns{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

button{
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s;
}

button:hover{
    transform: translateY(-2px);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #333333;
}

#calc-btn, .final__btn{
    width: 50%;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #a52a2a;
}

#reset-btn{
    width: 45%;
    border: 1px solid #a52a2a;
    color: #a52a2a;
    background-color: transparent;
}


/* ========== Output ========== */
#data-outputs{
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 2rem;
    padding: 25px;
}

.outputs{
    background-color: #a52a2a;
}

.result__container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}


/* ========== Footer ========== */
footer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #a52a2a;  
}
```

```html
        <header class="header">
            <h1>Net Salary</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="container">
            <main class="main">
                <div class="data__inputs" id="data-inputs">
                    <div class="inputs">
                        <input type="number" placeholder="Cout Journalier" id="cj-input">
                        <input type="number" placeholder="Nombre jour" id="nj-input">
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="btns">
                        <button type="reset" id="reset-btn">reset</button>
                        <button id="calc-btn">calcul</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="data__outputs" id="data-outputs">
                    <div class="outputs">
                        <div class="result__container">
                            <span class="output__title">Base Salary :</span>
                            <span id="slrBase-result">0 $</span>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="result__container">
                            <span class="output__title">Prime :</span>
                            <span id="prime-result">0 $</span>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="result__container">
                            <span class="output__title">Net Salary :</span>
                            <span id="slrNet-result">0 $</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button type="reset" class="final__btn" id="back-input">OK</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>

        <footer class="footer">
            <p>Copyright &#169; 2020-2021 Aatmane. All rights reserved</p>
        </footer>
```

Comment: step 1 of the debugging process: simplify your code. None of the CSS is relevant to the question, so just remove it, it's not part of your problem. Same with all the HTML around the calculator: it's not part of the problem, remove it. Turning your code in a [mcve] is far more about "you discovering the problem without anyone's help" than it is about having concise code that shows off your problem for your post, but if at the end of reducing your code to MCVE form you still have the same problem, _now_ you have appropriate code to post.

Answer (score 1):

You are using simple inputs not a form, a simple way will be setting the value to empty like this

```
function displayInputs() {
  outputPage.style.display = "none";
  inputPage.style.display = "initial";
  let coutJour = document.querySelector("#cj-input"),
    nbrJour = document.querySelector("#nj-input");
  coutJour.value = "";
  nbrJour.value = "";
}
```

or use a form instead and use the reset button or the .reset() function for the form

Answer (score 0):

An `button type="reset"` will only work when it is inside of a `form` element. And, if you have a `form` element, then a `button` element with no `type` automatically becomes a `type="submit"`, so if you don't want it to submit, it should be a `type="button"`.

In the code below, note that a `form` element starts just after your `header` and closes just before your `footer`.

```js
var 
    displayResultBtn = document.querySelector('#calc-btn'),
    backToInputBtn = document.querySelector('#back-input');

var 
    inputPage = document.querySelector('#data-inputs'),
    outputPage = document.querySelector('#data-outputs');

/* ========== Go to Result ========== */
displayResultBtn.addEventListener('click', displayResult);

function displayResult(){

    var 
        coutJour = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#cj-input').value),
        nbrJour = parseInt(document.querySelector('#nj-input').value),
        prime;

    // calcul Base Salary
    slrBase = coutJour * nbrJour;


    if(nbrJour>=25){
        prime = 200;
    }
    else if(nbrJour>=20){
        prime = 150;
    }
    else if(nbrJour>=15){
        prime = 100;
    }
    else if(nbrJour<15){
        prime = 50;
    }

    //calcul Net Salary
    var slrNet = slrBase + prime;

    //display results in his places
    document.querySelector('#slrBase-result').innerHTML = slrBase + " $";
    document.querySelector('#prime-result').innerHTML = prime + " $";
    document.querySelector('#slrNet-result').innerHTML = slrNet + " $",
    document.querySelector('#slrNet-result').style.color = "red";

    // display the result Page
    inputPage.style.display = "none";
    outputPage.style.display = "flex";
}

/* ========== Back to inputs ========== */
backToInputBtn.addEventListener('click', displayInputs);

function displayInputs(){
    outputPage.style.display = "none";
    inputPage.style.display = "initial";
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 10% 85% 5%;
}


/* ========== Header ========== */
header{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #a52a2a;
}

header h1{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .05rem;
    color: #fff;
}

main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* ========== Input ========== */
#data-inputs{
    display: initial;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 25px;
}
  
.inputs{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

input{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
}

input::placeholder{
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

input:focus{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a52a2a;
}

.btns{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

button{
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s;
}

button:hover{
    transform: translateY(-2px);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #333333;
}

#calc-btn, .final__btn{
    width: 50%;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #a52a2a;
}

#reset-btn{
    width: 45%;
    border: 1px solid #a52a2a;
    color: #a52a2a;
    background-color: transparent;
}


/* ========== Output ========== */
#data-outputs{
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 2rem;
    padding: 25px;
}

.outputs{
    background-color: #a52a2a;
}

.result__container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}


/* ========== Footer ========== */
footer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #a52a2a;  
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
            <h1>Net Salary</h1>
        </header>
   <form>
        <div class="container">
            <main class="main">
                <div class="data__inputs" id="data-inputs">
                    <div class="inputs">
                        <input type="number" placeholder="Cout Journalier" id="cj-input">
                        <input type="number" placeholder="Nombre jour" id="nj-input">
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="btns">
                        <button type="reset" id="reset-btn">reset</button>
                        <button type="button" id="calc-btn">calcul</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="data__outputs" id="data-outputs">
                    <div class="outputs">
                        <div class="result__container">
                            <span class="output__title">Base Salary :</span>
                            <span id="slrBase-result">0 $</span>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="result__container">
                            <span class="output__title">Prime :</span>
                            <span id="prime-result">0 $</span>
                        </div>
        
                        <div class="result__container">
                            <span class="output__title">Net Salary :</span>
                            <span id="slrNet-result">0 $</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <button type="reset" class="final__btn" id="back-input">OK</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
  </form>
        <footer class="footer">
            <p>Copyright &#169; 2020-2021 Aatmane. All rights reserved</p>
        </footer>
```